# Why does base64-encoded data compress so poorly?

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

I was recently compressing some files, and I noticed that base64-encoded data seems to compress really bad. Here is one example:

- Original file: **429,7 MiB**
- compress via `xz -9`:
  `13,2 MiB / 429,7 MiB = 0,031` `4,9 MiB/s` `1:28`
- `base64` it and compress via `xz -9`:
  `26,7 MiB / 580,4 MiB = 0,046` `2,6 MiB/s` `3:47`
- `base64` the original compressed xz file:
  `17,8 MiB` in almost no time = the expected `1.33x` increase in size

So what can be observed is that:

- xz compresses really good ☺
- base64-encoded data doesn't compress well, it is 2 times larger than the unencoded compressed file
- *base64-then-compress* is significantly worse and slower than *compress-then-base64*

How can this be? Base64 is a lossless, reversible algorithm, why does it affect compression so much? (I tried with gzip as well, with similar results).

I know it doesn't make sense to *base64-then-compress* a file, but most of the time one doesn't have control over the input files, and I would have thought that since the actual information density (or whatever it is called) of a base64-encoded file would be nearly identical to the non-encoded version, and thus be similarily compressible.

Comment: "_base64-then-compress_ is significantly worse and slower than _compress-then-base64_" - not to mention that the two are for all intents and purposes unrelated.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Most generic compression algorithms work with a **one-byte granularity**.

Let's consider the following string:

```
"XXXXYYYYXXXXYYYY"
```

- A Run-Length-Encoding algorithm will say: *"that's 4 'X', followed by 4 'Y', followed by 4 'X', followed by 4 'Y'"*
- A Lempel-Ziv algorithm will say: *"That's the string 'XXXXYYYY', followed by the same string: so let's replace the 2nd string with a reference to the 1st one."*
- A Huffman coding algorithm will say: *"There are only 2 symbols in that string, so I can use just one bit per symbol."*

Now let's encode our string in Base64. Here's what we get:

```
"WFhYWFlZWVlYWFhYWVlZWQ=="
```

All algorithms are now saying: *"What kind of mess is that?"*. And they're not likely to compress that string very well.

As a reminder, Base64 basically works by re-encoding groups of 3 bytes in (0...255) into groups of 4 bytes in (0...63):

```
Input bytes    : aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc
6-bit repacking: 00aaaaaa 00aabbbb 00bbbbcc 00cccccc
```

Each output byte is then transformed into a printable ASCII character. By convention, these characters are (here with a mark every 10 characters):

```
0         1         2         3         4         5         6
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

For instance, our example string begins with a group of three bytes equal to 0x58 in hexadecimal (ASCII code of character "X"). Or in binary: 01011000. Let's apply Base64 encoding:

```
Input bytes      : 0x58     0x58     0x58
As binary        : 01011000 01011000 01011000
6-bit repacking  : 00010110 00000101 00100001 00011000
As decimal       : 22       5        33       24
Base64 characters: 'W'      'F'      'h'      'Y'
Output bytes     : 0x57     0x46     0x68     0x59
```

Basically, the pattern "3 times the byte 0x58" which was obvious in the original data stream is not obvious anymore in the encoded data stream because we've broken the bytes into 6-bit packets and mapped them to new bytes that now appear to be random.

**Or in other words: we have broken the original byte alignment that most compression algorithms rely on.**

Whatever compression method is used, it usually has a severe impact on the algorithm performance. That's why you should always compress first and encode second.

This is even more true for encryption: compress first, encrypt second.

**EDIT - A note about LZMA**

As MSalters noticed, LZMA -- which xz is using -- is working on bit streams rather than byte streams.

Still, this algorithm will also suffer from Base64 encoding in a way which is essentially consistent with my earlier description:

```
Input bytes      : 0x58     0x58     0x58
As binary        : 01011000 01011000 01011000
(see above for the details of Base64 encoding)
Output bytes     : 0x57     0x46     0x68     0x59
As binary        : 01010111 01000110 01101000 01011001
```

Even by working at the bit level, it's much easier to recognize a pattern in the input binary sequence than in the output binary sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So base64 is "obfuscating" the repetitions in the bitstream. Interestingly, @MSalters has a point that part of the issue is that my data is well compressible, if I give `xz` data from `/dev/urandom`, it doesn't compress at all (as expected), but `/dev/urandom` through `base64` compresses down to ~77%, very close to the theoretical maximum of 75% via Huffman coding.

Comment: Yes, any algorithm implementing Huffman coding will at the very least figure out that only 64 out of 256 symbols (bytes in that case) are used in a Base64-encoded string. For random data, all 64 symbols should get a uniform distribution, hence leading to a compression ratio of ~75%.

Comment: plus 1 for "All algorithms are now saying: "What kind of mess is that?". "

Comment: It would be cool if a compression tool was smart enough to detect Base64 encoding, then change its compression algorithm to handle it better (e.g. decode first before compression.)

Comment: @JordanRieger http://www.tc4shell.com/en/7zip/edecoder/
 - eDecoder plugin for 7-Zip adds `eSplitter` codec, that (de)codes base64 parts in email, mhtml and similar file formats, to compress in binary form separately from text parts, possibly with different compression methods. In several month of using it I have yet to meet a case where it did not give better compression for supported formats. There is also `Smart7z` which should automate choosing methods, but I personally don't use it.

Answer (score 11):

Compression is necessarily an operation that acts on multiple bits. There's no possible gain in trying to compress an individual "0" and "1". Even so, compression typically works on a limited set of bits at a time. The LZMA algorithm in `xz` isn't going to consider all of the 3.6 billion bits at once. It looks at much smaller strings (<273 bytes).

Now look at what base-64 encoding does: It replaces a 3 byte (24 bit) word with a 4 byte word, using only 64 out of 256 possible values. This gives you the x1.33 growth.

Now it is fairly clear that this growth must cause some substrings to grow past the maximum substring size of the encoder. This causes them to be no longer compressed as a single substring, but as two separate substrings indeed.

As you have a *lot* of compression (97%), you apparently have the situation that very long input substrings are compressed as a whole. this means that you will also have many substrings being base-64 expanded past the maximum length the encoder can deal with.

Answer (score -10):

It's not Base64. its them memory requirements of libraries "The presets 7-9 are like the preset 6 but use bigger dictionaries and have higher compressor and decompressor memory requirements."https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-javadoc/org/tukaani/xz/LZMA2Options.html