# Compressing Base64 String is not of less size

Tags: java, string, base64, compression, deflate

I'm trying to compress a Base64 String using the java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream and Deflater clases. My problem is that after compression the size is not less from both cases. For the first case with the GZIPInputStream the size is bigger, and in the second case with the Deflater  class the size is almost the same.

The output of my code is:

```
Original String Size: 8799
CompressedGZip String Size: 8828
UncompressedGZip String Size: 8799
Original_String_Length=8799
Compressed_String_Length Deflater=8812, Compression_Ratio=-0.147%
Decompressed_String_Length Deflater=8799 == Original_String_Length (8799)
Original_String == Decompressed_String=True
```

As you can see in both cases the compressed string is not less. I need to compress the input base64 String because in some cases is too long. Is there any way to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
       private static String compressFileGZip(String data) {
        try {

            // Create an output stream, and a gzip stream to wrap over.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
            GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);

            // Compress the input string
            gzip.write(data.getBytes());
            gzip.close();
            byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
            bos.close();

            // Convert to base64
            compressed = Base64.getEncoder().encode(compressed);

            // return the newly created string
            return new String(compressed);
        } catch(IOException e) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String decompressFileGZip(String compressedText) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // get the bytes for the compressed string
        byte[] compressed = compressedText.getBytes("UTF8");

        // convert the bytes from base64 to normal string
        Base64.Decoder d = Base64.getDecoder();
        compressed = d.decode(compressed);

        // decode.
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);

        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
        }
        gis.close();
        is.close();
        return string.toString();
    }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
        String compressedGZip = compressFileGZip(input);
        String compressedDeflater = null;
        String uncompressedGZip = null;
        String decompressed = null;
        try {
            compressedDeflater = compress(input);
            uncompressedGZip = decompressFileGZip(compressedGZip);
            decompressed = decompress(decodeBase64(compressedDeflater));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Original String Size: " + input.length());
        System.out.println("CompressedGZip String Size: " + compressedGZip.length());
        System.out.println("UncompressedGZip String Size: " + uncompressedGZip.length());

        Integer savedLength = input.length() - compressedDeflater.length();
        Double saveRatio = (new Double(savedLength) * 100) / input.length();
        String ratioString = saveRatio.toString() + "00000000";
        ratioString = ratioString.substring(0, ratioString.indexOf(".") + 4);
        println("Original_String_Length=" + input.length());
        println("Compressed_String_Length Deflater=" + compressedDeflater.length() + ", Compression_Ratio=" + ratioString + "%");
        println("Decompressed_String_Length Deflater=" + decompressed.length() + " == Original_String_Length (" + input.length() + ")");
        println("Original_String == Decompressed_String=" + (input.equals(decompressed) ? "True" : "False"));
        // end
    }


    public static String compress(String str) throws Exception {
        return compress(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static String compress(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(bytes);
        deflater.finish();
        //deflater.deflate(bytes, 2, bytes.length);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while(!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
        byte[] output = bos.toByteArray();
        return encodeBase64(output);
    }

    public static String decompress(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(bytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
        byte[] output = bos.toByteArray();
        return new String(output);
    }

    public static String encodeBase64(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return base64Encoder.encodeBuffer(bytes).replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "");
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBase64(String str) throws Exception {
        BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        return base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(str);
    }

    public static void println(Object o) {
        System.out.println("" + o);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to read this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126771) and reconsider your approach. You also can set the compression level on the Deflater, but that won't make a difference for that kind of data.

Comment: If you're able to transmit arbitrary byte data, why are you encoding in Base64 in the first place?

Comment: I am getting the image as a Base64 String and I have to store this value in the database, I would like to know if it is possible to compress this long String in a shorter text, so that I can't apply the strategy of compress first and encode second, if it is not possible what strategy can I apply?

Comment: @rasilvap The [answer linked to by second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742052/compressing-base64-string-is-not-of-less-size#comment101923538_57742052) shows that Base64 always compresses badly, because the encoding obfuscates compressionable patterns. So to compress the data, do it before the Base64 encoding. Of course, most *image* formats are already compressed, so there is nothing you can do. It is already as compressed as it's going to get.