# Performance side of using base64 encoded images in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, base64

I am creating a full screen slider which can contain both images and videos.These medias are loaded from Firebase as the client needs to updated this through a control panel.
With `getStaticProps` i am able to fetch the urls from server and pass it to the slider component, However there is some delay and glitches in the smoothness of slider as we are only passing the download url of media to the slider component.

So with my little knowledge i am thinking to convert the `url` to `base64` from `getStaticProps` itself and pass it to slider.

Mostly the images  will be around 2MB and videos will be 5-10 MB.

**1) I know that base64 will take much more storage but as i am doing it in the server at build time only will this cause any other side effects when user visits the site? or is this a bad practice?**

**2) If the above one is ok then i am getting some warning in console from `getStaticProps`
like

`Warning: data for page “/” is 150 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance.`
is it ok to avoid this? or do i need to write the encoded to some JSON file and read it from there?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you partially answered your question

> Mostly the images will be around 2MB and videos will be 5-10 MB.

> 1. I know that base64 will take much more storage but as i am doing it in the server at build time only will this cause any other side effects when user visits the site? or is this a bad practice?

In general, `base64` is for smaller sized images is preferred.
Because you do not specify how many images and videos they can upload - you could eventually end up with a large html as more and more assets are uploaded.  Remember base64 is not a [compression mechanism per se](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126771/13749957)

Other options you should consider

1. Use `next/image` and [built in image optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization) - This even works for remote images.
2. Load via an image transcoding service like imgix or cloudinary